# Error in install.packages("devtools"): dependencies not available

Tags: r, installation, package, devtools

I'm trying to install the `devtools` package which results in a `non-zero exit status` error.

Installiere Paket nach ‘/Users/jupyter-sbr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3’
(da ‘lib’ nicht spezifiziert)

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’
* removing ‘/Users/jupyter-sbr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/textshaping’
ERROR: dependency ‘textshaping’ is not available for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/Users/jupyter-sbr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/ragg’
ERROR: dependency ‘ragg’ is not available for package ‘pkgdown’
* removing ‘/Users/jupyter-sbr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/pkgdown’
ERROR: dependency ‘pkgdown’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/Users/jupyter-sbr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/devtools’
```

I tried `pip install devtools` (no error message):

```
Requirement already satisfied: devtools in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asttokens<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from devtools) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: executing>=1.1.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from devtools) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from asttokens<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->devtools) (1.16.0)
```

but this did not change anything.

Do you know what I could try? Thank you!!

**EDIT:** `install.packages("textshaping")` results in:

```
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed to find the harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi library. Try installing:
 * deb: libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: harfbuzz-devel fribidi-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
 * csw: libharfbuzz_dev libfribidi_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: harfbuzz fribidi (OSX)
If harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: hb-ft.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’
* removing ‘/Users/jupyter-sbr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/textshaping’

Die heruntergeladenen Quellpakete sind in 
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpk3HSmQ/downloaded_packages’
Warnmeldung:
In install.packages("textshaping") :
  Installation des Pakets ‘textshaping’ hatte Exit-Status ungleich 0
```

and `install.packages("fribidi")`:

```
package ‘fribidi’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere
```

Comment: why are you using `pip` if it's R?

Comment: @user2554330, I did! See the edit above!

Comment: Try restarting Rstudio completety

Comment: Does not help... Other packages can be installed, the problem remains for the devtools package.

Comment: @user2554330 This is not really correct as OP is on Linux and as the error message clearly suggests needs library packages `libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev`.  Moreover the `devtools` package is likely also available as a binary.

Comment: Just look at the error message of the package (`textshaping`). It says everthing clearly.  OP has provided sufficient information to guestimate which distro this is on; as added option (as we see jupyter ...) one could resort to Conda.  The key is that _installing from source_ is hard(er) for some people less familiar with it so binaries are key.  And just about any distro that has R will likely have a `devtools` binary package.

Comment: I never implied you could.  OP can, because OP is on his machine.  All we can see is that it is Linux meaning that the top two of the four lines displayed by `textshaping` (in a very standard form used by other R packages too) apply here as Debian/Ubuntu and Fedora are two common forms.  But we know for sure macOS or Windows does not apply so all this song and dance about `fribidi` is just plain _wrong_.   (And yes, I have also installed `textshaping` many times, and I do not have or not `fribidi` the command-line tool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @user2554330 said, the issue is that Fribidi (the command line utility) isn't installed. It can be installed:

- on Mac with [`brew install fribidi`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/fribidi)
- on Linux, with whichever package manager you use (`pacman`, `apt get`, `rpm` etc.)
- on Windows, the best option is likely to be [building it from source](https://github.com/fribidi/fribidi#building)

Update: The problem was with the 'harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi library' (I overlooked one of OPs errors )

```
Configuration failed to find the harfbuzz freetype2 fribidi library. Try installing:
 * deb: libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: harfbuzz-devel fribidi-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
 * csw: libharfbuzz_dev libfribidi_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: harfbuzz fribidi (OSX)
```

Install harfbuzz as directed above Credit: @DirkEddelbuettel